# Inside an O'Neill cylinder, would a Pendulum's swing have any notable characteristics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centrifugal-force

Objects inside an [O'Neill Cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Neill_cylinder) would feel the Centrifugal effect, given by: $F=mω^2r$, and the Coriolis effect, given by: $F=d(mv)/dt$, as well as air friction from air under the same effects.

At the two extremes of the swing, the pendulum would be (at least slightly) closer to the center of the cylinder's axis, and thus experience less "gravity" from the Centrifugal effect. /
Unless perpendicular to the direction of spin, the pendulum would be going against the Coriolis effect in one direction of the swing, and be aided by it in the return direction.

***In layman's terms*, what would be the observed results of these conflicting forces on a swinging pendulum?**

Answer (score 2):

Not noticeable.

On Earth, gravity is slightly weaker at the extreme ends of a pendulum's swing as well, because it's farther away from the center of the Earth. But, it turns out that deviation is small enough that purely geometric effects invalidate the harmonic oscillator approximation for large swing angles long before gravity becomes an issue.

The whole point of an O'Neill cylinder is to be big enough that the gravity feels normal to humans. Thus, while the drop-off of apparent gravity with height on an O'Neill cylinder follows a different equation than gravity on Earth, within the range of angles for which pendulums behave approximately harmonically, it won't make any observable difference. At large angles, it will become shaky and irregular, in ways that *are* chaotically different from how they would be on Earth... but are *chaotically* different from how they are on Earth, so no human observer would be able to pick out the differences.

Meanwhile, the tangential velocity at the inner surface of an O'Neill cylinder is just over 195m/s. Your pendulum will not move at any significant fraction of that speed, so the difference in effective gravity on the foreswing vs. the backswing will also be below the margin of error for any human observer.

Comment: I doubt there won't be any noticeable changes. The conservation of the momentum of inertia - Foucault pendulum. If the oscillation plane is along the "equator" (normal to the cylinder axis), nothing happens. If it's at any other angle, the pendulum will necessary precess.

Comment: [Rate of rotation: 2.6 degrees/second = 38 full rotations/hours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Neill_cylinder#Artificial_gravity) - the precession will be noticeable/evident at sub-minute time scale. Furthermore, the same source indicates Coriolis force are strong enough to cause motion sickness in _some people_ - if the inner ear is sensible enough to pick unusual effects, they will absolutely be noticeable on a longer pendulum. Be it only for these reasons, the "Not noticeable." answer is wrong.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi A Foucault pendulum does not precess at the equator. And in an O'Neill cylinder, the entire interior surface is the equator. Gravity is always perpendicular to the axis of rotation.

Comment: The two aren't equivalent. A limit case to help you see there are differences: set your pendulum suspension point on the cylinder axis - what's the period of small oscillations and why is it different than in Earth case?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi That depends on the plane of oscillation. But far from the axis, that ceases to matter, as the gravitational field is well-approximated as constant. The same is true on Earth--theoretically, a pendulum swinging along the equator should behave differently from one swinging perpendicular to the equator, but in practice it does not, because the effect sizes are far too small.

Comment: Then check if the same "small" condition is applicable to the cylinder as well. You have a radius of Earth of 6.357e6m, a Foucault pendulum of 67m and a vertical amplitude of oscillations at probably 25-50mm. For the same approximation to be viable in the O'Neill cylinder (radius of 8km), you will have to get a Foucault pendulum of 8cm and an oscillation amplitude of 63$\mu{m}$ Hardly an experiment that can involve perception.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi The deviations don't have to be *as ridiculously small* as they are on Earth to still be small enough to not be worth bothering about.

Comment: [O'Neill cyclinder/Artificial gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Neill_cylinder#Artificial_gravity) "People would, however, be able to detect spinward and antispinward directions by turning their heads, and any dropped items would appear to be deflected by a few centimetres." I call "just turning the head to detect rotation direction" something definitely noticeable. My apologies, but until you come with some formulae to show what scale is needed for the effects to become "noticeable", I will remain unconvinced by your claim on the contrary.